# CAS: User logged in as another user

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

Is it possible that a user puts in his/her credentials and gets logged in as **someone else** while using **CAS**? I am currently using **CAS 3.4.8** and a grails-app that uses spring security core and cas as client that uses CAS. There had been some customization done to CAS server but not to the overall flow of it.

So is it a bug in the CAS server? Is there any other known cases that resembles this issue?

EDIT 1
The problem got solved. I was using a servlet filter for loading custom themes for CAS that varied according to the url. This was causing concurrency issues. I moved the logic into a spring bean and moved it to login-weblow.xml and the issue was fixed.

Comment: What kind of customizations were made? Is it deterministic?

Comment: Szymon, the customization was done for authentication that is done once users post their credentials from the login from. This is hit just once during login, the rest of the web flow is the same.

Comment: You may have multiple applications with under same CAS. I think you have logged out from one but not the others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the CAS chairman and I've never heard of a bug of that kind : "being logged as someone else". I tend to think that the culprit is your customization : do you properly take into account the multi-threading aspect ?

Comment: jleleu, is there anyway the UsernamePasswordCredentials object that is used while generating tickets (ST, TGT etc) gets swapped for different users. This issue is very hard to replicate and does not happen 95 percent of the time. Also, could you please tell me more about the multi-threading aspect you were talking about. Thanks

Comment: If it's nondeterministic, then it's almost certain, that a race condition is involved. You can start by checking, if an application scoped bean (Spring) doesn't store any session related data.

Comment: Follow Szymon's advice or check that a customized bean use instance properties to store user's data...

Comment: Hi Szymon and jleleu thanks for the reply. I checked if an application scoped bean is storing any session related data, but it is not. It got replicated today when two users logging in at the same time, but it looks like their jsessionid is getting swapped.

Comment: The application that is trying to autheincate via CAS is a grails-app and uses spring security cas and core. When, user A got logged in as user B, it had a session id appended with the url that belonged to user B. It was like this..https://my.grails.app.com/appA/;jsessionid=7F78317B4CF0B835774B1E527892D0DF. This session id did not belong to the userA that got logged in as userB, it belonged to userB. Shouldn't the web-container be handling the session id's? -Thanks

Comment: Your JSESSIONID's problem is strange, but yes, you can control the app server or even through the web.xml (servlet 3) that you don't want any session id to be put into urls...

Comment: Hi jlelu, I found this bug in tomcat that resembles my issue. It says "A session fixation flaw was found in the way FormAuthenticator module of Apache Tomcat, an Apache Servlet/JSP Engine, performed authentication requests management in certain circumstances (the most recent authentication request was associated with current user's session). An attacker could use this flaw to inject (and possibly successfully to complete) an authentication request, that would be executed using the credentials of the victim." It was posted on https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2013-2067

Comment: So @jleleu could this be the issue? Also I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526425/spring-security-with-cas-skips-session-fixation-protection) that implies CAS is vulnerable to session-fixation? -Thanks

Comment: The link you propose is not related to the CAS server but to the CAS client using Spring Security. I think that the problem with Tomcat (JSESSIONID cookie in url) can be the root cause. Use disableURLRewriting="true" in Tomcat context definition.